# Find a string within a field

Tags: sql, mysql, string

This may be easy but I am new to this so here it goes.  I am trying to find if a string can be found in a mysql database field.

The following will only find exactly match

```
SELECT mycontact, userid
FROM mytable
WHERE email = #form.email#'
```

The following will return result if the field email is contain in the form.email

```
 SELECT mycontact, userid
 FROM mytable
 WHERE email like '%#form.email#%'
```

But these will not give what I want.  I want the reverse of the above.  The email field can contain MORE than one email addresses.  I want to be able to enter a value i.e. form.email and search the table and find any record in the "email" field that contain form.emal.  The %LIKE% won't work because I don't want to retrieve more than one.  If someone enter cd@gmail.com, I don't want to get abcd@gmail.com, bcd@gmail.com etc.   That is the difficult part. Help is appreciated.  I am using MYSQL database.  Thanks.

Comment: i agree with Donnie below BUT if you aren't going to separate email addresses into rows, how do you separate them when you have multiples?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me exactly how you are storing multiple emails in a single field.  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to redesign your schema, having a list of emails in a column is a very, very bad design and SQL isn't well designed to handle it (as you're running into already).  Better would be an `email` table where each `contact` can have one or more rows based on the email addresses they provide.

Trust me, it'll work better, and make your life a lot easier.  Redesign now.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [regular expressio](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)n for the selection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing more than one email in a field you should add a delimiter like a space or a pipe.  You can do

```
SELECT mycontact, userid FROM mytable WHERE email like '%#form.email#%'
```

then explode the delimiter and loop in array.  Compare each email by using pregmatch.  But I would recommend you to use a separate table for this as what they said above.  I would totally agree with them.